# jQuery: Creating a circular slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, draggable

You may have seen JavaScript sliders before:

http://dev.jquery.com/view/tags/ui/1.5b2/demos/ui.slider.html

What I'm envisioning is a circular slider. It would consist of a draggable button at one point on the circle -- and that button can be dragged anywhere along the ring. The value depends on what position the button is at (think of a clock).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

define a center point c
current mouse point at m

in your mouse drag event handler, you'd have

```
var dx = m.x-c.x;
var dy = m.y-c.y;

var scale = radius/Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);

slider.x = dx*scale + c.x;
slider.y = dy*scale + c.y;
```

radius would be some preset value of the slider,

Comment: how would you implement this I was looking for the same thing and found this thread but I have no idea how I would implement that code

Comment: same question math is plenty easy, but how would you implement the frontend? how do you structure this using div's and such?

Comment: The math behind : Parametric equation of circle

http://www.mathopenref.com/coordparamcircle.html

Answer (score 1):

How about this: http://www.thewebmasterservice.com/dev-blog/curved-rounded-or-circular-sliders-javascript-jquery-ui

Some explanations and a demo.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/princejwesley/circular-slider) which supports full/half circle sliders.

[Demo Page](http://www.toolitup.com/circular-slider.html) & [Documentation](https://github.com/princejwesley/circular-slider/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

Check the jQuery roundSlider plugin from here http://roundsliderui.com/. This is what you want exactly.

This roundslider having the similar options like the jQuery ui slider. It support default, min-range and range slider type. Not only the round slider it also supports various [circle shapes](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html#various-circle-shapes) such as **quarter**, **half** and **pie** circle shapes.

For more details check the [demos](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html) and [documentation](http://roundsliderui.com/document.html) page.

Please check the demo from [**`jsFiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/utqgufx0/).

**Related answers:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/31367164/1845801 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/31369265/1845801

**Screenshots:**

[image: jquery circular sliders - different circle shapes]