# round slider select

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, 360-degrees

Is there a jQuery-based 360 rotational slider, where the user can grab the end and rotate it 360 degrees?

Comment: I found a thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351371/jquery-creating-a-circular-slider but it does not show how to implement and its not really a jquery plugin I left a comment hoping to get closer to my goal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this example at [interface.eyecon.ro](http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/drag_vr.html), it has a circle and a draggable handle and from looking at the page source it's not too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The only proper way for you to get this done in a way a client appreciates is by diving into HTML CANVAS element. I don't think one has been done for your purpose but I remember a while ago I saw soundmanager api company experimenting with 360 sliders in canvas for seeking time laps of sound on their player.

Comment: that's an idea but I don't have the time or energy to write this code I might just have to go with a horizontal or vertical slider. I'm surprised that jquery-ui slider doesn't have a circle option

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very late answer but i hope this is useful for the upcoming users.

An jQuery [roundSlider](http://roundsliderui.com/) plugin is a perfect plugin for your requirement.

This roundslider having the similar options like the jQuery ui slider. It support default, min-range and range slider type. Not only the round slider it also supports various [circle shapes](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html#various-circle-shapes) such as quarter, half and pie circle shapes.

For more details check the [demos](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html) and [documentation](http://roundsliderui.com/document.html) page.

Please check the live demo from [**`jsFiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/LpuLe9tr/).

**Screenshot of the Output:**

[image: default round slider - jQuery plugin]
[image: min-range round slider - jQuery plugin]
[image: range round slider - jQuery plugin]