# Round Jquery UI slider

Tags: jquery, slider, range, jquery-knob

I'm looking for something similar to [jqueryui slide](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range).

But the main problem in my case it's round design for slider. I've seen [Knob control](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/) but it doesn't have range and control buttons.

Shoot me a link if you know such an example. Thanks.

Comment: you can use 2 Knob controls and get the job done! One for the min range and one for the max range, just you have to somehow manage that they do not cross each other's values.

Comment: Also see if this helps : http://www.websitemaintenancelabs.com/dev-blog/curved-rounded-or-circular-sliders-javascript-jquery-ui

Answer (score 1):

Check the jQuery roundSlider plugin from here http://roundsliderui.com/. This is what you want exactly.

This roundslider having the similar options like the jQuery ui slider. It support default, min-range and range slider type. Not only the round slider it also supports various [circle shapes](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html#various-circle-shapes) such as quarter, half and pie circle shapes.

For more details check the [demos](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html) and [documentation](http://roundsliderui.com/document.html) page.

Please check the demo from [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/LpuLe9tr/1/).

**Live demo:**

```js
$("#slider").roundSlider({
    sliderType: "range",
    value: "20,80"
});
```

```css
#slider{
  margin: 10px auto 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.roundslider/1.0/roundslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.roundslider/1.0/roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="slider"></div>
```

**Screenshots with different theming:**

[image: round slider - different theme and appearance]
[image: circular slider - different theme and appearance]
[image: radial slider - different theme and appearance]

Check more details about different theme from [here](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html#different-theming-and-appearances).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example at [interface.eyecon.ro](http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/drag_vr.html), it has a circle and a draggable handle and from looking at the page source it's not too complicated.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.