# Circular Slider using Jquery

Tags: html5-canvas, jquery-slider

How to slide mouse in circular ?
Draw an arc and a mouse pointer in a canvas. Mouse should be drag gable on the circular path?

```
//function to create mouse event to drag the mouse hover the arc

function mousedrag() {
    var canvasoffset = $(this.canvas).offset();
    var offsetX = canvasoffset.left;
    var offsetY = canvasoffset.top;     
    var mouseX = parseInt(e.offsetX || e.clientX - offsetX);
    var mouseY = parseInt(e.offsetY || e.clientY - offsetY);

    var radius = this.width / 2;
    var twoPI = 2 * Math.PI;
    var toRad =  twoPI / 360;
    var r_width =  this.width * 0.8;

    var radial_Angle = Math.atan2(mouseY - radius,mouseX - radius);

    var p_side_x =  radius + r_width * Math.cos(radial_Angle);        
    var p_side_y =  radius + r_width * Math.sin(radial_Angle);
    var p_mouse_x =  radius + ((r_width+10) * Math.sin(radial_Angle));
    var p_mouse_y =  radius + ((r_width+ 10) * Math.sin(radial_Angle));

    var imgData = this.ctx.getImageData(p_side_x, p_side_y, 1, 1).data;
    var selectedColor = new Color(imgData[0], imgData[1], imgData[2]);
            clearDraw();
    renderSpectrum();
    renderMouse(p_side_x, p_side_y, p_mouse_x, p_mouse_y);          
}
```

mouse handle does not slide properly.

Comment: does not draw mouse handle at the circle. show in the diagonal line

Answer (score 5):

You can't actually force the mouse to be constrained into a circle.

But you can calculate the mouse position relative to a centerpoint.

```
// define a centerpoint

var cx=150;  
var cy=150;
var angleVersusCenter=0;

// listen for mouse moves 

function handleMouseMove(e){

  // get the mouse position

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // set the current radian angle of the mouse
  // versus the centerpoint

  var angleVersusCenter = Math.atan2( mouseY-cy, mouseX-cx );
}
```

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/z6cQB/

[image]

Comment: I tried with code but not working properly ( [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/HYwCV/11/) ). I saw example in [html5](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-bounds-tutorial-with-kineticjs/) to bound the drag vertical or horizontal. Need help to create handle mouse event. Thanks to the above information. it was very helpfull suggestion

Comment: Is it possible to have canvas layers. so that I can avoid redraw of the background

Comment: Yes, you could do layers so the background is not disturbed.  Could you describe what you need in better detail--it seems I don't fully understand what you want :(

Comment: I am trying to create a colorpicker

Comment: I'm confused about what you need :-(  If you want a color picker you could draw an image of a colorwheel and then get the pixel color under the mouse?

Comment: Is it possible to modify the code in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/HYwCV/19/) . I want avoid redrawing of arc every time when I draw handle. –

Comment: I am still confused about what you need :-(  That fiddle shows a fixed arc and a circle that moves with the mouse. What would you like it to do?

Comment: Above code is not showing the handle properly . How to convert mouse position into radian_angle centered at point (x,y). And then how to get the x1,y1 at a radius from a radiant angle ?.

Comment: From the example I found using atan2 to get the radiant_angle and R*Cos(radiant_anlge) to get the x1 coordinate it is not working properly when I move the mouse. Mouse is doesn't not slide properly in circular.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the jQuery roundSlider plugin for your requirement, check here http://roundsliderui.com/. This might helps you.

This roundslider having the similar options like the jQuery ui slider. It support default, min-range and range slider type. Not only the round slider it also supports various [circle shapes](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html#various-circle-shapes) such as quarter, half and pie circle shapes.

For more details check the [demos](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html) and [documentation](http://roundsliderui.com/document.html) page.

Please check the demo from [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/LpuLe9tr/2/).

**Live demo:**

```js
$("#slider").roundSlider({
    width: 10,
    handleSize: "+8",
    value: "40"
});

$("#half-slider").roundSlider({
    width: 10,
    circleShape: "half-top",
    handleSize: "+8",
    value: "80"
});
```

```css
.rs-control {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.rs-control .rs-path-color {
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.roundslider/1.0/roundslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.roundslider/1.0/roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="slider" class="rslider"></div>

<div id="half-slider" class="rslider"></div>
```

**Screenshots with different appearances:**

[image: round slider - jquery plugin]
[image: circular slider - jquery plugin]
[image: arc slider - jquery plugin]

Check more details about different theme from [here](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html#different-theming-and-appearances).